# selecionar mutliples valores de un array y mostrarlo en un multselc

Tags: javascript

como agrupar varios valores que me va arrojando el array a una sola variable. por los momentos solo muestra una sola pero quiero que muestre mas de una

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se me ocurrió hacerlo de esta manera y hacer un recorrido por infodivi e ir comparandolo con el array de divisiones pero solo me toma el primer valor que posee el infodivi  y anota el valor que posee...

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataInit.infodivi.length; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j < self.comboDivisiones.length; j++) {
            if (dataInit.infodivi[i].id === self.comboDivisiones[j].id) {
             self.form.divisiones.value = self.comboDivisiones[j];
             self.form.divisiones.disabled = false;
            }}}
```

para luego mostrarlo de la siguiente manera en un multiselect, en este caso tomo el id 4 en este caso seria Metodo y Procesos, mientras que lo que contenia el id 3 no lo muestra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En javascript tenemos disponibles algunas funciones para cualquier array. Puedes consultarlas en la página de Mozilla Developer Network (MDN). 
Te recomiendo, si vas a hacer uso frecuente de algún elemento en el dom, guardar su referencia en una variable, para no buscar una y otra vez.

En este caso, el primer paso sería obtener los elementos del array A (divisiones) que existen en el array B (infodivi). Yo usaría map(), porque ya tenemos un array cuyos objetos podemos ocupar de base para encontrar los elementos del array *divisiones*

```
const existentes = infodivi.map(existente => divisiones.find( divi => divi.id === existente.id))
```

Luego puedes operar sobre este arreglo para manipular las opciones de tu input.